# Laravel, Strip Non-numeric, cuts off input

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have a Integer field in my db called "price"

I have a basic text form field for this

```
{{ Form::text('price', Input::old('price'), array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

I want to strip all non number inputs from this field

in my Controller:

```
$price = Input::get('price');
$price = (string)$price;
$price = preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", $price);
$price = (int)$price;
$this->title->price = $price;
```

However when I run this code if I enter eg.

```
123123,2432223
```

It'll only ever save `123123` to my DB, the input after the comma is never saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are casting a string to an integer. Integers are whole numbers. You want to cast to a (float) or (double).

Aside from that the `,` is not seen as a decimal point. a `.` is.

```
$this->title->price = (float) preg_replace("/[^\d,./]/", "", Input::get("price"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$this->title->price = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', Input::get('price'));
```

Comment: i know i tried something like this before, but for some reason your code works, and mine didn't